# Modifier readonly is not valid for get only property

Tags: c#

I try to implement singleton

```
public static readonly MyClass Instance { get; } = new MyClass();
```

However Visual Studio tells me, I cannot use readonly for this item. Why is that?

Comment: Read only property is used with properties only, in which you can only set value on run time inside the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readonly` is a valid modifier for fields.

For properties you can control if and who can write/read with `get` and `set`. `readonly` doesn't make sense on a property.